# Add description for String.prototype.myMethod

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

How can I add JSDoc description for method (Extended Native Objects)?

I want to see this description of the method in Visual Studio Code.

```
/**
 * My description.
 */
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
console.log('foo'.capitalize()); // Foo
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVlnV.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define your own properties inside JavaScript you can use Symbol for that because symbols are unique. But you should access this properties using square brackets not dot notation.

```js
/**
 * My description.
 */
const capitalize = Symbol('capitalize');
 String.prototype[capitalize] = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
 }
console.log('foo'[capitalize]());
// Foo
```